# What do the various patrol icons mean?

Tags: destiny

When you are patrolling,  Nav Mode shows missions with an icon. So far I only know the pyramid icon is a 'Kill and collect' mission.

What do each of the icons mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it turns out, there's [a post on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2gz5fo/here_are_the_patrol_mission_icons/) with an image that answers this nicely:

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that in the 1.0.3 patch the icon for 'Item Mission' has changed.